# Elementor plugin not working on a VPS/WHM with CSF & CFX , how to solve it?

Tags: wordpress, vps, elementor, csx, csf

i have a VPS Centos7 with CPanel Certificate from contabo. Elementor is not working on all wordpress sites hosted on this VPS. I tryed all the debugging solutions but still not working ..
I have cfs and cfx installed on this VPS, I think there is a rule in these plugins configuration that causes this Elementor problem .. meanwhile, i have another VPS hosted on contabo  Centos7 + CPanel  and working well ..
any ideas how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I've vps in contabo,  and elementor work fine. I think the problem is in files and folders  permissions and  owner of files and folders. Owner must be apache's user (someone like "www-data").